Unable to get import to fix "onClick" unrecognized giving error
I'm new to Kotlin and I'm following a Room tutorial but (at about 32 minutes) I get an error that I wasn't able to fix:

This is my code:
@Composable
fun ContactScreen(
    state: ContactState,
    onEvent: (ContactEvent) -> Unit
){
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick ={
                onEvent(ContactEvent.ShowDialog)
            }){
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add contact")
            }

        }
    ){padding ->
        LazyColumn (
            contentPadding = padding,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ){

        }
    }
}

these are my imports:
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

This is the screenshot of the video (I checked every comma and parenthesis)


You have the wrong FloatingActionButton imported. It should be androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton.

@MikeM. Thanks, It fixed. Do you want to post an answer (so I can accept) or do you think I have to delete the question?

No problem. I'd just consider this a typo, so feel free to delete. Thanks, though, for the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

@MikeM. Thanks again and see you on the next bug ;)

@MikeM. I thinked on it: It wasn't a typo. The problem is that the video doesn't show the needed imports! So this post can be helpful to someone else. Please post an answer and let me accept it.

You're right, it's technically not a typo, but wrong imports are generally considered as such here on SO. If you think this question will help others, definitely keep it. I was just letting you know that I don't mind if you want to delete it. Indeed, I don't post answers here anymore, so please feel free to add one yourself to finish this up. Thanks again, though. Cheers!

The solution is in the comment:
You have the wrong FloatingActionButton imported. It should be androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton. –
Mike M.
Thanks to Mike
